# Ubuntu Dual Boot with Win8

Tags: windows-8

I recently managed to dual boot win8 and Ubuntu 13.10 successfully. However after I updated the UBUNTU OS and restarted the machine, I no longer get the OS selection screen when booting. My system boots straight into the win 8.

How can I successfully update my UBUNTU and still have my Dual boot with Win 8 working properly?

Answer (score 1):

- .Log in into your windows 8 os.Download and install EasyBCD from [*`here`*.](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/EasyBCD-Download-45820.html)
- .Under linux section,set grub2 as bootloader add a boot entry for your Ubuntu Partition.
  And also add entry for your windows 8 partition.
- reboot

Or

- try [`boot-repair disk`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) .
  Manual: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair